# Run TestDFSIO test on sub set of CDH 5 beta nodes

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, cloudera

I have got Cloudera CDH 5 beta cluster set up on five nodes across two ESXi servers:

```
ESXi Server 1 :
 1. NameNode VM
 2. DataNode1 VM
 3. DataNode3 VM

ESXi server 2:
 1. DataNode3 VM
 2. DataNode4 VM
```

I want to run TestDFSIO test so that it runs on only ESXi 1 VMs.
i.e I want to make sure that test runs on VMs which are on same network.

What configuration parameter should I change for this?

I am running following commands.

**TestDFSIO commands :**

**Write:**

```
sudo -u hdfs hadoop jar /opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.0.0-0.cdh5b1.p0.57/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/hadoop-test-2.2.0-mr1-cdh5.0.0-beta-1.jar TestDFSIO -write -nrFiles 100 -fileSize 10GB -resFile /tmp/TestDFSIOwrite.txt
```

**Read:**

```
sudo -u hdfs hadoop jar /opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.0.0-0.cdh5b1.p0.57/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/hadoop-test-2.2.0-mr1-cdh5.0.0-beta-1.jar TestDFSIO -read -nrFiles 100 -fileSize 10GB -resFile /tmp/TestDFSIOread.txt
```

Do I need to modify my commands with some config. options?

Answer (score 0):

You should probably stop the other datanodes before running the test.  You can't limit TestDFSIO to run on a subset of nodes.